# Error using 'residuals' on moving average for ts

Tags: vector, time-series, moving-average, forecast

I have been working on forecasting using ts object. In order to test the accuracy of a moving average, I used the code below:

```
fixt_ma <- ma(fixtures_training, 3)
residuals(fixt_ma)
acc_fixt_ma <- accuracy(fixt_ma, fixtures_test)
```

**dput for fixtures_training**

```
structure(c(161L, 338L, 393L, 405L, 439L, 386L, 442L, 406L, 413L, 
421L), .Tsp = c(2019.48076923077, 2019.65384615385, 52), class = "ts")
```

When I use the *residuals(fixt_ma)* function, or alternatively when I write the code like *residuals$fixt_ma*, I get the error below:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forecast::ma` does moving average smoothing. It is not a model and so it has no residuals.

Perhaps you wanted an MA(3) model, in which case you could use

```
fixt_ma <- Arima(fixtures_training, order=c(0,0,3))
```

Then `residuals()` will work:

```
residuals(fixt_ma)
#> Time Series:
#> Start = c(2019, 26) 
#> End = c(2019, 35) 
#> Frequency = 52 
#>  [1] -79.553356  99.757891 -16.836345  -8.949918  42.906861   4.752855
#>  [7]  39.762007 -29.453682  47.281713  11.804971
```

However `accuracy()` will give an error using the code in your question. If you want forecast accuracy measures on the test set, you first have to produce forecasts:

```
fc_ma <- forecast(fixt_ma, h=length(fixtures_test))
acc_fixt_ma <- accuracy(fc_ma, fixtures_test)
```